# Something is blocking port 25 - how to debug?

Tags: centos7

I have been struggle with an issue for the last 3 weeks. I've recently acquired a new vps server, and for some reason something is blocking port 25 and I cannot find what.

```
Step to reproduce:
telnet smtp.1and1.es 25
```

- traceroute on port 25 to any server will fail on the first hop.

**I checked**
- DNS and are fine as the domain is converted to the ip, and ping work as expected.

- I have disabled fail2ban and firewall by doing:

  service fail2ban stop
  service firewalld stop

Tried again, telnet smtp.1and1.es 25

And same result timeout.

All maillogs show unreachable host on port 25, for all emails notifications.

It is a VPS so there is an external firewall, the external firewall is all open.

So I wondering what else cloud be blocking the port?

It is definitely an issue with outgoing traffic on 25. But I can't find what is blocking it.

```
iptables -L

Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
f2b-plesk-wordpress  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports http,https,empowerid,7081
f2b-plesk-login  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports cddbp-alt,pcsync-https
f2b-BadBots  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports http,https,empowerid,7081
f2b-apache  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports http,https,empowerid,7081
f2b-plesk-roundcube  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports http,https,empowerid,7081
f2b-plesk-horde  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports http,https,empowerid,7081
f2b-plesk-dovecot  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports imap,imap3,imaps,pop3,pop3s,sieve
f2b-plesk-postfix  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports smtp,urd,submission
f2b-plesk-proftpd  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports ftp,ftp-data,ftps,ftps-data
f2b-recidive  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            
f2b-SSH    tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp flags:!FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN state NEW reject-with tcp-reset
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state INVALID
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:12443
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:11443
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:11444
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:8447
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:pcsync-https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:cddbp-alt
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ftp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:submission
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:smtp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:urd
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:pop3
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:pop3s
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:imap
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:imaps
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:poppassd
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:mysql
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:postgres
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ogs-server
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:glrpc
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-ns
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-dgm
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:netbios-ssn
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:microsoft-ds
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:openvpn
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmptype 8 code 0
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp flags:!FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN state NEW reject-with tcp-reset
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state INVALID
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp flags:!FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN state NEW reject-with tcp-reset
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state INVALID
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain f2b-BadBots (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain f2b-SSH (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain f2b-apache (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain f2b-plesk-dovecot (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain f2b-plesk-horde (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain f2b-plesk-login (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain f2b-plesk-postfix (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain f2b-plesk-proftpd (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain f2b-plesk-roundcube (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain f2b-plesk-wordpress (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain f2b-recidive (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     all  --  223.71.208.114       anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  221.229.172.75       anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  278660.customer.zol.co.zw  anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  118.70.168.251       anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Comment: what does the local firewall says? `iptables -L`

Comment: Where is the VPS hosted? Some hosting providers block outgoing port 25, until you ask them to open it up (to avoid spam robots).

Comment: I asked them, they confirmed is open. I will add iptables results

Comment: If your provider doesn't block port 25, it's probably used by spammers, so its IP ranges are probably blacklisted by the servers you're trying to connect to.

Comment: @MikeScott: if other servers are blocking it, then the traceroute could pass at least the first hop, isn't?

Comment: @peterpeterson You can't traceroute to a specific port, so your traceroutes are probably failing because you've mangled the syntax in some way by trying to specify port 25.

Comment: [traceroute __does__ support port tracing](https://linux.die.net/man/8/traceroute) for tcp. I guess the problem is, that udp on port 25 gets dropped; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16809214/is-smtp-based-on-tcp-or-udp *edit* sorry - forget about outgoing udp - I mixed your input and output chains

Answer (score 2):

Most VPS companies prohibit and block outbound traffic on port 25 to stop them being used for spamming. You'll need to use a third-party mail relay that listens on a different port (which may well be a service that your VPS company can provide).