# Postfix can receive but can't send external

Tags: debian, postfix, dovecot, debian-stretch

I recently installed ispconfig 3 from this manual: https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial...-9-stretch-apache-bind-dovecot-ispconfig-3-1/
But now the problem is; I can receive mail from external clients but I can't send mail to external clents.
I used gmail and my old hotmail account but neither of those is receiving.
I also checked if my server is block by a spam filter, but even that wasn't the case.
My mail.log:

```
Aug 13 11:08:03 server1 dovecot: imap(admin@dkict.com): Logged out in=44 out=592
Aug 13 11:08:18 server1 postfix/qmgr[6091]: 5E5DE4625BF: from=<>, size=5323, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug 13 11:08:18 server1 postfix/qmgr[6091]: 034B9460D91: from=<>, size=4949, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug 13 11:08:18 server1 postfix/qmgr[6091]: CE59B4625CE: from=<test@dkict.com>, size=909, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug 13 11:08:25 server1 postfix/smtpd[9261]: connect from localhost[::1]
Aug 13 11:08:25 server1 postfix/smtpd[9261]: warning: table "mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_client.cf": empty query string -- ignored
Aug 13 11:08:25 server1 postfix/smtpd[9261]: NOQUEUE: filter: RCPT from localhost[::1]: <admin@dkict.com>: Sender address triggers FILTER amavis:[12$
Aug 13 11:08:25 server1 postfix/smtpd[9261]: 7D8B246021F: client=localhost[::1]
Aug 13 11:08:25 server1 postfix/cleanup[9262]: 7D8B246021F: message-id=<8d024ea696db4366e8d63e9f629bc680@dkict.com>
Aug 13 11:08:25 server1 postfix/qmgr[6091]: 7D8B246021F: from=<admin@dkict.com>, size=575, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug 13 11:08:25 server1 dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<admin@dkict.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=::1, lip=::1, mpid=9265, secured, session=<4BKH455WpuI$
Aug 13 11:08:26 server1 postfix/smtpd[9261]: disconnect from localhost[::1] ehlo=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=5
Aug 13 11:08:26 server1 dovecot: imap(admin@dkict.com): Logged out in=472 out=640
Aug 13 11:08:26 server1 dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<admin@dkict.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=::1, lip=::1, mpid=9269, secured, session=<H1Kb455WqOI$
Aug 13 11:08:27 server1 dovecot: imap(admin@dkict.com): Logged out in=70 out=633
Aug 13 11:08:30 server1 postfix/smtpd[9270]: connect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Aug 13 11:08:30 server1 postfix/smtpd[9270]: 8C5C54625DB: client=localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Aug 13 11:08:30 server1 postfix/cleanup[9262]: 8C5C54625DB: message-id=<8d024ea696db4366e8d63e9f629bc680@dkict.com>
Aug 13 11:08:30 server1 postfix/qmgr[6091]: 8C5C54625DB: from=<admin@dkict.com>, size=1042, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug 13 11:08:30 server1 amavis[3182]: (03182-07) Passed CLEAN {RelayedOutbound}, ORIGINATING LOCAL [::1]:33772 <admin@dkict.com> -> <tiger-dennis@ho$
Aug 13 11:08:30 server1 postfix/smtp[9263]: 7D8B246021F: to=<tiger-dennis@hotmail.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10026, delay=5.3, delays=0.25/0.0$
Aug 13 11:08:30 server1 postfix/qmgr[6091]: 7D8B246021F: removed
Aug 13 11:08:30 server1 postfix/smtpd[9270]: disconnect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1] ehlo=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=5
Aug 13 11:08:32 server1 dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<admin@dkict.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=::1, lip=::1, mpid=9280, secured, session=<ayPp455WruI$
Aug 13 11:08:32 server1 dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<admin@dkict.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=::1, lip=::1, mpid=9281, secured, session=<lzHp455WsOI$
Aug 13 11:08:32 server1 dovecot: imap(admin@dkict.com): Logged out in=120 out=766
Aug 13 11:08:32 server1 dovecot: imap(admin@dkict.com): Logged out in=318 out=1951
Aug 13 11:09:03 server1 postfix/smtp[9260]: connect to mx3.hotmail.com[65.55.92.168]:25: Connection timed out
Aug 13 11:09:08 server1 postfix/smtp[9259]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.69.26]:25: Connection timed out
Aug 13 11:09:08 server1 postfix/smtp[9259]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:4013:c04::1b]:25: Network is unreachable
Aug 13 11:09:08 server1 postfix/smtp[9259]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2404:6800:4003:c03::1b]:25: Network is unreachable
Aug 13 11:09:08 server1 postfix/smtp[9258]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.69.26]:25: Connection timed out
```

My main.cf:

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.cert
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.key
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = server1.dkict.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases, hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases, hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination =
relayhost =
mynetworks = localhost

mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
html_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/html
virtual_alias_domains =
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/virtual-mailman, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_forwardings.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_email2email.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailboxes.cf
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
virtual_uid_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_uids.cf
virtual_gid_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_gids.cf
sender_bcc_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_outgoing_bcc.cf
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_restriction_classes = greylisting
greylisting = check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10023
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination, reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org, check_recipient_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_recipient.cf, check_recipient_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_policy_greylist.cf
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
transport_maps = hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/transport-mailman, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_transports.cf
relay_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_relaydomains.cf
relay_recipient_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_relayrecipientmaps.cf
smtpd_sender_login_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_sender_login_maps.cf
proxy_read_maps = $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_alias_domains $sender_bcc_maps $virtual_mailbox_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $relay_recipient_maps $relay_domains $canonical_maps $sender_canonical_maps $recipient_canonical_maps $relocated_maps $transport_maps $mynetworks $smtpd_sender_login_maps
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, check_helo_access regexp:/etc/postfix/helo_access, reject_invalid_hostname, reject_non_fqdn_hostname, reject_invalid_helo_hostname, reject_unknown_helo_hostname, check_helo_access regexp:/etc/postfix/blacklist_helo
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access regexp:/etc/postfix/tag_as_originating.re , permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, check_sender_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_sender.cf, check_sender_access regexp:/etc/postfix/tag_as_foreign.re
smtpd_client_restrictions = check_client_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_client.cf
smtpd_client_message_rate_limit = 100
maildrop_destination_concurrency_limit = 1
maildrop_destination_recipient_limit = 1
virtual_transport = dovecot
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
mime_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/mime_header_checks
nested_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/nested_header_checks
body_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/body_checks
owner_request_special = no
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtpd_tls_exclude_ciphers = RC4, aNULL
smtp_tls_exclude_ciphers = RC4, aNULL
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
content_filter = amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
receive_override_options = no_address_mappings
message_size_limit = 0
```

Thanks in common!

Comment: The error message `connect to mx3.hotmail.com[65.55.92.168]:25: Connection timed out` indicates a firewall that blocks outgoing SMTP traffic (TCP port 25). That might be your own local firewall, or, typically when you're using  either a consumer ISP or  a corporate network , that might be a policy to force you to send all outgoing email messages through an SMTP relay to enforce local email policies and to prevent (compromised) systems from sending spam

Comment: Hi Hbruijn, I found what the problem is. I'm with ziggo as ISP, Ziggo has blocked port 25 as outgoing connection, this is set for business users and private users to prevent being added to the blacklist for spammers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Something is blocking port 25 - how to debug?](https://serverfault.com/questions/813186/something-is-blocking-port-25-how-to-debug)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user of my ISP I am not allowed to set port 25 as outgoing connection.
I have to select an other port.
https://community.ziggo.nl/thuisnetwerk-101/poort-25-mailserver-geblokkeerd-voor-ziggo-13680 (page is in dutch)
Whole issue resolved by adding a relay host!